# How to send expression from View to Model then parse and calculate it?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have something like simple MS Windows Calculator in ASP.NET MVC 4. Now I don't know how to send expression like `4+5` to the Model for example to `public string Expression { get; set }`. Then I want parse this expression and calculate it but how to do it?

I have Controller:

```
public class CalculatorController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Calculator/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //GET: /Calculator/Calculate
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Calculate(Calculator model)
    {

        return View(model);
    }
    //POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Calculate()
    {
        Calculator model = new Calculator();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I have Model:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public string Expression { get; set; }
    public double Result { get; set; }
}
```

And I have View with Razor and JavaScript:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate", "Calculator", FormMethod.Post)){    
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Expression)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Expression)    
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="btnSeven" id="btnSeven" value="7" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnEight" value="8" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnNine" value="9" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="DEL" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnClear" value="CLR" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnFour" value="4" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnFive" value="5" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnSix" value="6" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnMultiply" value="*" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnDivide" value="/" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnOne" value="1" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnTwo" value="2" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnThree" value="3" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnPlus" value="+" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnMinus" value="-" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnZero" value="0" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnDot" value="." /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" id="btnEqual" value="=" /></td>
                @Html.ValueFor(model => model.Expression)
                <td><input type="button" id="btnLBracket" value="(" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnRBracket" value=")" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

}

JavaScript in the same View:

```
<script>
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('btnSeven').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnSeven').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnEight').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnEight').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnNine').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnNine').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnDelete').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnDelete').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnClear').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnClear').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnFour').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnFour').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnFive').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnFive').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnSix').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnSix').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnMultiply').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnMultiply').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnDivide').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnDivide').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnOne').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnOne').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnTwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnTwo').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnThree').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnThree').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnPlus').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnPlus').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnMinus').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnMinus').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnZero').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnZero').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnDot').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnDot').value;
                });
                @*document.getElementById('btnEqual').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnEqual').value;
                });*@
                document.getElementById('btnLBracket').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnLBracket').value;
                });
                document.getElementById('btnRBracket').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById('Expression').value = document.getElementById('Expression').value + document.getElementById('btnRBracket').value;
                });
            }
```

How to send expression to `Expression` then parse and calculate and send to `Result` and then send to the `textBox`. Everything must be done in the same textBox after click on `=` button.

Comment: Why don't you do it all in the javascript? It's only simple maths calculations

Comment: You can post the string Expression using Ajax, and refresh your results.

Comment: Yes, I know it would be simpler in javascript but I need to do it in ASP.NET MVC 4 architecture (Model-View-Controller).